# Jquery Validation multiple checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, checkbox

Im trying to validate multiple checkbox groups using the jquery validation plugin with this html structure...

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1_0" value="one" id="cbxGroup1_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1_0" value="two" id="cbxGroup1_1">Two </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1_0" value="one" id="cbxGroup2_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbxGroup1_0" value="two" id="cbxGroup2_1">Two </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

JS Validation code:

```
$("#myForm").validate({

                invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                alert("Debe llenar todos los campos");
                $('.ui-submit').removeClass('ui-btn-active');

                },
                submitHandler: function(){
//something}

            });
```

But i cant get working, the checkbox always take different names and id, im trying to put a class for the checkbox but when the validation trigger, ask me for every checkbox, and I want at least 1 per group.

Can anyone help me... thks

Comment: Your names are dirty. Aren't they? I think cbx1 and cbx2 isn't fine in one checkbox group?

Comment: well the structure i write it's not the same... in reality the names are equal of the id value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array in the `names`

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="group1[1]" value="one" id="cbxGroup1_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="group1[2]" value="two" id="cbxGroup1_1">Two </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Checkbox Group (required)</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="group2[1]" value="one" id="cbxGroup2_0">One </label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="group2[2]" value="two" id="cbxGroup2_1">Two </label>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Then, you can control that each array has length different from 0.

However, I didn't get the thing you are trying to do with class ... can you be more specific.

Comment: I cant change the name, and for the class, im put in every checkbox class="required"